# C++ Clearing wstring

Tags: c++, wstring

My problem is that no method that used to work on string works on wstring.
So I'm asking how I could easily clear `wstring` for aesthetical purpose.

My code right now:

```
    while (!foundRightOne)
    {
        wstring cTitle;
        ForegroundWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
        cout << "FRGW  " << ForegroundWindow << endl;

        int len = GetWindowTextLengthW(ForegroundWindow) + 1;
        wchar_t * windowTitle = new wchar_t[len];
        GetWindowTextW(ForegroundWindow, windowTitle, len);
        title += windowTitle;
        // OUTPUT
        cTitle = L"Title: ";
        cTitle += title;
        wcout << cTitle << endl;
        cTitle = ' ';
        //OUTPUT
        keyPress = getchar();
        system("CLS");
        if (keyPress == 'y' || keyPress == 'Y')
        {
            foundRightOne = true;
        }

    }
```

Basically it loops while I press `y` or `Y`, I press when I see the right `cTitle` and after *~20* cycles cTitle gets fully filled with text from last cycles.

Comment: `std::string` and `std::wstring` are exactly the same except for the character type they store. Anyway, a space is not a cleared string and a character literal is not a wide character, much like how a string literal is not a wide string.

Comment: The code is no test case. Please provide the definition of 'title'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::wstring::clear` should work, as both it and `std::string` are `std::basic_string`s. Check out [std::basic_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/clear) documentation if you're somehow having trouble.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string regularString("regular string!");
    std::wstring wideString(L"wide string!");

    std::cout << regularString << std::endl << "size: " << regularString.size() << std::endl;
    std::wcout << wideString << std::endl << "size: " << wideString.size() << std::endl;

    regularString.clear();
    wideString.clear();

    std::cout << regularString << std::endl << "size: " << regularString.size() << std::endl;
    std::wcout << wideString << std::endl << "size: " << wideString.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
regular string!
size: 15
wide string!
size: 12

size: 0

size: 0
```

Here's an [ideone](http://ideone.com/Vhdzwv) link to that code.

Comment: Thanks. Now i'm really confused. After checking size() it says 0, but it still outputs OLD titles. [link]http://i.imgur.com/W52gvIM.png - Screenshot

Comment: @Ufonautas did you try setting it to an empty string? `cTitle = ""` or re-initializing it via `cTitle = std::wstring()`